# Opening a new jframe with the same properties as the closed one

Tags: java, swing, positioning, jframe, sizing

How can I have the newly open jframe have the same properties like Size and position on screen. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in *size and position* JFrame.getBounds returns these properties:

```
newFrame.setBounds(oldFrame.getBounds());
```

---

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    final JFrame oldFrame = new JFrame("Test");

    oldFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("Test");
            newFrame.setBounds(oldFrame.getBounds());
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    oldFrame.setSize(400, 300);
    oldFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: please amend nonExist method setPosition with ... http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: @mKorbel: Updated that minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1):

@Sam that not good idea to create new [TopLevelContainer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on fly, better would be reuse exist [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and just replace/switch its contents [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and if you need/want to display more TopLevelContainers then others would by [JDialog(s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

please check how to [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) works (with examples there) and tons of example about Swing on [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)